# Como lidar com o uso do getline() em um for(;;)?

Tags: c++

Estou armazenando os nomes de autores de livros em um vetor string.

```
     for(int i = 0; i<qt; i++)
        {
            cin >> nome;
            NOME[i] = nome;
        }
```

Mas quero ter o nome completo, nome e sobrenome, então pensei em fazer:

```
for(int i = 0; i<qt; i++)
        {
            getline(cin,nome);
            NOME[i] = nome;
        }
```

Mas, se `qt == 2` por exemplo, ele só vai ler o nome de um autor, tipo "Flavio melo", depois de ler o primeiro ele não vai ler o segundo nome.

Então tentei:

```
for(int i = 0; i<qt; i++)
        {
            LIMPA_BUFFER;
            getline(cin,nome);
            NOME[i] = nome;
        }
```

Onde `LIMPA_BUFFER;` faz `cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n')`. Mas ainda assim, ele vai ler o nome do primeiro autor, do segundo, e depois pula pra um terceiro autor! (ainda no caso em que `qt == 2`). Quando vou imprimir o vetor com os nomes dos autores, não imprime nome nenhum.

Como faço para ler os nomes completos, armazenar no vetor, e mostrar os nomes normalmente utilizando o `getline()`?

Aqui segue o código completo da implementação da TAD:

Meu problema está no `case 1:` e no método `inserir_autor()`

```
# include <iostream>
# include <stdio.h>
# include <stdlib.h>
# include <climits>
# include <cassert>

#define TAM_max 10
#define LIMPA_BUFFER    cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n')

using namespace std;

class Livro
{
private:
    friend class Data;

    string *Autores;
    string Titulo;
    int aux = 0;

public:

    Livro ()
    {
        Autores = new string [TAM_max+1];
    }

    /// Titulo do livro
    void titulo_livro (string titulo)
    {
        Titulo = titulo;
    }

    /// Adiciona os autores principais
    void inserir_autor (string* &nome_aut, int qt)
    {
        aux = qt;
        for(int i = 0; i<qt; i++)
        {
            Autores[i] = nome_aut[i];
        }

    }

    /// Adiciona mais autores
    bool inserir_mais_autores (string novo_aut)
    {
        if(aux < TAM_max)
        {
            Autores[aux] = novo_aut;
            aux++;
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;

    }

    /// Remove um autor
    bool remover_autor (string autor_remv)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i<TAM_max ; i++)
        {
            if(Autores[i] == autor_remv)
            {
                for(int j=i; j<TAM_max; j++)
                {
                    Autores[j] = Autores[j+1];
                }
                aux--;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    /// Altera o titulo
    void altera_titulo (string novo_titulo)
    {
        Titulo = novo_titulo;
        cout << "\n Seu novo Titulo: " << Titulo << endl;
    }



    /// Altera autor
    bool altera_autor (string autor, string novo_autor)
    {
        for(int i = 0 ; i<TAM_max; i++)
        {
            if(Autores[i] == autor)
            {
                Autores[i] = novo_autor;
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;

    }

    /// Imprime os dados do livro
    void imprime_livro()
    {
        cout << "\t Dados do livro:" << "\n" << endl;
        cout << "\n Titulo: " << Titulo << endl;
        cout << "\n Autores: \n" << endl;
        for(int i = 0 ; Autores[i] != "" ; i++)
        {
            cout<< "[" << i+1 << "] = " << Autores[i] << "\n" <<endl;
        }
    }

};


class Data
{
private:
    friend class Livro;
    int DIA = 0, MES = 0, ANO = 0;

public:

    bool verifica_data(int dia, int mes, int ano)
    {
        if( (dia >= 1 && dia <= 31) && (mes >= 1 && mes <= 12) ) //verifica se os numeros sao validos)
        {
            if ((dia == 29 && mes == 2) && ((ano % 4) == 0 && (ano % 100)!= 0 || (ano % 400) == 0)) //verifica se o ano e bissexto
            {
                return true;
            }
            if (dia <= 28 && mes == 2) //verifica o mes de fevereiro
            {
                return true;
            }
            if ((dia <= 30) && (mes == 4 || mes == 6 || mes == 9 || mes == 11)) //verifica os meses de 30 dias
            {
                return true;
            }
            if ((dia <=31) && (mes == 1 || mes == 3 || mes == 5 || mes == 7 || mes ==8 || mes == 10 || mes == 12)) //verifica os meses de 31 dias
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
    }

    void inserir_data(int dia, int mes, int ano)
    {
        DIA = dia;
        MES = mes;
        ANO = ano;
    }

    void imprime_data()
    {
        cout << " Data de Publicacao: " << "\n" << endl;
        cout << DIA << "/" << MES << "/" << ANO << "\n" <<endl;
    }

};

int main()
{

    Livro L;
    Data D;

menu:

    cout << "\n" << endl;
    system("cls");

    int op=0;
    cout << "\tEstante Virtual\n" << endl;
    cout << "1 - Cadastrar livro" << endl;
    cout << "2 - Imprimir dados" << endl;
    cout << "3 - Remover um autor(a)" << endl;
    cout << "4 - Inserir novo autor(a)" << endl;
    cout << "5 - Alterar nome do livro" << endl;
    cout << "6 - Alterar data de publicacao" << endl;
    cout << "7 - Alterar nome de um autor(a)" << endl;
    cout << "0 - Encerrar programa"<< "\n"  << endl;

    cin >> op;
    switch (op)
    {
    case 0:
        return 0;

    case 1:
        {
            system("cls");

            int qt = 0;
            int dia = 0, mes = 0, ano = 0;
            bool valida_data;
            string titulo;

            cout << " Nome do livro: \n" << endl;
            LIMPA_BUFFER;
            getline(cin, titulo);
            L.titulo_livro(titulo);

            cout << "\n Informe a quantidade de autores: \n" << endl;
            cin >> qt;

            while(qt > 0)
            {
                if(qt > 0 && qt <= TAM_max)
                    break;
                else
                {
                    cout << "\n Informe no minimo 1 e no maximo 10 autores" << endl;
                    cin >> qt;
                }

            }

            cout << "\n Informe seus nomes: \n" << endl;
            string *NOME = new string [TAM_max+1];
            string nome;

            for(int i = 0; i<qt; i++)
            {
                cin >> nome;
                NOME[i] = nome;
            }


            L.inserir_autor(NOME,qt);

            cout << "\n Data de publicacao: \n" << endl;
            cin >> dia >> mes >> ano;
            valida_data = D.verifica_data(dia,mes,ano);
            if(valida_data == true)
            {
                D.inserir_data(dia,mes,ano);
            }
            else
            {
                while(valida_data == false) //Enquanto não for válido, então...
                {
                    cout << "\n Data invalida! \n\n Informe uma data de publicacao valida: \n" << endl;
                    cin >> dia >> mes >> ano;
                    valida_data = D.verifica_data(dia,mes,ano);
                }
                D.inserir_data(dia,mes,ano);
            }

            system("cls");
            cout << " Cadastro efetuado com sucesso! \n" << endl;
            system("pause");
            break;
        }

    case 2:
        {
            system("cls");
            L.imprime_livro();
            D.imprime_data();

            system("pause");
            break;
        }

    case 3:
        {
            system("cls");
            string autor_remv;

            cout << " Informe o autor que deseja remover: " << endl;
            cin >> autor_remv;

            bool valor = L.remover_autor(autor_remv);
            if(valor == true)
                cout << "\n Autor removido com sucesso! \n" << endl;
            else
                cout << "\n Autor inexistente! \n" << endl;

            system("pause");
            break;
        }

    case 4:
        {
            system("cls");
            string autor;
            bool valor;

            cout << " Informe o nome do autor: " << endl;
            cin >> autor;

            valor = L.inserir_mais_autores(autor);
            if(valor == true)
                cout << "\n Autor cadastrado com sucesso! \n" << endl;
            else
                cout << "\n Limite maximo de autores atingido! \n" << endl;

            system("pause");
            break;
        }

    case 5:
        {
            system("cls");
            string novo_titulo;

            cout << " Informe o novo nome para o livro: \n" << endl;
            LIMPA_BUFFER;
            getline(cin, novo_titulo);
            L.altera_titulo(novo_titulo);
            cout << "\n Titulo alterado com sucesso! \n" << endl;

            system("pause");
            break;

        }

    case 6:
        {
            system("cls");
            int dia = 0, mes = 0, ano = 0;

            cout << " Informe a nova data: \n" << endl;
            LIMPA_BUFFER;
            cin >> dia >> mes >> ano;
            D.inserir_data(dia,mes,ano);

            cout << "\n Data alterada com sucesso! \n" << endl;

            system("pause");
            break;

        }

    case 7:
        {
            system("cls");
            string autor, novo_autor;
            bool valor;

            cout << " Informe o nome do autor que sera modificado:" << endl;
            cin >> autor;

            cout << "\n Informe o novo nome:" << endl;
            cin >> novo_autor;

            valor = L.altera_autor(autor, novo_autor);

            if(valor == true)
                cout << "\n Autor renomeado com sucesso! \n\n" << endl;
            else
                cout << "\n '" << autor << "' nao foi encontrado! \n\n" << endl;

            system("pause");
            break;

        }
    }
    goto menu;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Coloque um código funcional demonstrando o problema.

Comment: @bigown, o código é bem grande, mas vou colocar.

Comment: Coloque só uma parte que mostre o problema de forma que dê para compilar e executar. http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @bigown, coloquei tudo logo, pode rodar ele. Vai na opção 1, e apenas siga as instruções. Agora meu problema é que quero adicionar o nome completo do autor e não consigo um bom comando ou lógica pra isso.

Comment: @FilipiMaciel Tem solução mais elegante, mas você pode simplesmente por mais de um getline no mesmo loop. Por exemplo ecoar na tela "digite o prenome", getline(), "digite o sobrenome", e outro getline() dentro do mesmo loop.

Comment: Eu não vou ter paciência para achar o erro para você. Se alguém tiver, você terá uma resposta. Fazer o MCVE é importante para facilitar quem vai te ajudar e para se desenvolver como criador de soluções. Como o texto lá fala, pode ser que você ache o problema sozinho tentando isolá-lo.

Comment: @Bacco, nesse caso, nome e sobrenome estariam em variáveis separadas? Pois se utilizar a mesma ele vai sobrepor. Se tiver em variáveis distintas, tipo uma pro nome e outra pro sobrenome, como eu colocaria essas variáveis juntas em uma única posição do vetor de strings?

Comment: @bigown, desculpe mas não entendi sua sugestão. O que seria MCVE?

Comment: Leia o *link* que eu te passei acima.

Comment: @FilipiMaciel só estou dando uma dica preliminar, vamos ver se sai alguma resposta boa que te atenda ;) . Eu sugeriria você pensar bem na estrutura desejada, e se for preciso acrescentar na pergunta todos os detalhes necessários da sua necessidade específica, aproveitando que não responderam ainda. Quanto ao MCVE, o link em azul que o bigown postou tem a explicação.

Comment: @bigown, Ah sim, obrigado, tentarei isso.

Comment: @Bacco, Tranquilo, pensarei em algo. Vou tentar levar isso pros meus colegas de curso, se conseguir resposta eu posto aqui. Obrigado!

Comment: @FilipiMaciel de curiosidade, qual seria o problema da pessoa digitar "Filipi Maciel" no mesmo getline? Teria algum motivo em especial de vc separar o nome e o sobrenome se vai por no mesmo lugar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma possível solução passa, como apresentaste na tua pergunta, pelo uso da função [getline](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline). 
A substituição neste caso é quase imediata. Apenas tens que assegurar que o buffer `cin` é limpo antes de usares a função `getline`. O teu código ficaria assim:

```
case 1:
    {
        system("cls");

        //(...)

        cout << "\n Informe seus nomes: \n" << endl;
        string *NOME = new string [TAM_max+1];
        string nome;

        //limpar buffer
        cin.clear();
        cin.ignore(INT_MAX, '\n');

        for(int i = 0; i<qt; i++)
        {
            //cin >> nome;
            getline(cin, nome);
            NOME[i] = nome;
        }

        L.inserir_autor(NOME,qt);

        //(...)

        system("cls");
        cout << " Cadastro efetuado com sucesso! \n" << endl;
        system("pause");
        break;
    }
```

Como comentário final, sugeria o uso da classe [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) ao invés do uso de apontadores para a classe string. No teu caso não existe vantagem alguma, pelo contrário, está a originar um "memory leak" (fuga/vazamento de memória):

Sempre que cadastras os nomes dos autores dos livros estás a alocar memória que nunca é libertada:

```
  string *NOME = new string [TAM_max+1];
```

Comment: Olá @bruno, testei e realmente funcionou. Eu tinha implementado uma solução bem deselegante, que foi o seguinte: 

Criei um `char NOMEAUX[100];` e utilizei a função `gets()` para ler e armazenar cada caractere dentro desse vetor. Em seguida passava esse vetor para `NOME[i] = nome;`, que aceitava passar uma sequência de caracteres e converte-los em uma única string. 

Sua solução deu certo, porém não consegui entender por que deveria limpar o buffer apenas uma vez antes de entrar no for, e também não entendi por que limpar o buffer dentro do for é um problema. Pode me ajudar nessas dúvidas?