# Erro de código C++ com getline(cin,string)

Tags: c++, string

Estou a aprender a programar em C++ e quando utilizo a funcao getline(cin,nome) nao consigo colocar texto la dentro e o codigo avanca para a linha seguinte. O programa deve perguntar idade e nome e é suposto ter um output que indica a idade e nome colocados no input.
Alguém me pode ajudar?
Obrigado

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int age;
    cout << "Insere a tua idade: ";
    cin >> age;

    string nome;
    cout << "Insere o teu nome: ";
    getline(cin, nome);

    cout << "Ola " << nome << "! Segundo a tua resposta tens: " << age << " anos" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ao você dar enter no `cout << "Insere tua idade: "` ele vai passar o `\n` ( enter) para o `cin >> age;`

Por sua vez será o primeiro caracter lido pelo `getline(cin, nome);` por isto esta linha é pulada.
Faça isto para resolver este problema:

```
cout << "Insere o teu nome: ";
while(getline(cin, nome))
   if(nome != ""){
          break;
    }
```

Há outras possibilidades de limpar o buffer usando o [cin.ignore](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/).

Recomendo a leitura: [Como lidar com o uso do getline() em um for(;;)?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/96260/como-lidar-com-o-uso-do-getline-em-um-for)

Comment: Muito obrigado resolveu o meu problema!

Comment: Acho que pergunto algo um bocado estúpido mas o que significa o "getline(cin, nome)". Como isso é uma condição?

Comment: @kikolaranjo desculpa a demora! Lembre-se disto: "nenhuma dúvida é estúpida". Basicamente é pq  C++ interpreta while(0) COMO FALSE e os demais numerais e caracteres são interpretados como TRUE! Esta pergunta irá sanar sua dúvida: [Para que serve while(0) e while(1) em C?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/104376/para-que-serve-while0-e-while1-em-c)

Comment: Se a resposta te ajudou,marque ela como aceita, veja como fazer isto no [Tour](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: Obrigado mais uma vez. Ajudou me muito!